# Kotlin - Java code coverage in Android studio showing 0% NOT WORKING

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-android-extensions

In one of my android project in Android studio, I have some source files written in Kotlin and there corresponding unit tests written in Java, Now when I try to run the test class with coverage it shows me 0%. All tests pass and runs fine but the coverage shows is 0%.

For the scenario where source file written in Java as well as there test class is also in Java it works perfectly fine, only issue is when source class is in kotlin and test class in Java or vice-versa.

```
Gradle Version : 4.1
Kotlin Version : 1.1.61
play_services = "11.8.0"//9.4.0
support_version = "27.1.0"//23.+
espresso = "3.0.1"

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //mockito
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9" // PowerMockito works on 2.8.9
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2"

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.9'
```

Any help is appreciated, Please let me know if anyone knows how to fix this. Thanks